# How to add duration in hours to time in HH:MM and obtain it in a new column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Example:

```
Start Date   Start Time   Duration (hours)
------------------------------------------
8/15/2016       3:10        15.58
------------------------------------------
8/16/2016       6:50        29.67
-----------------------------------------
7/28/2016       1:30        8.17
-----------------------------------------
```

How to obtain new columns called 'End Date' and 'End time' which is the result of adding 'Duration (hours)' to 'Start time'?

Desired output:

For example if we assume a rainfall record:

Start Date: 8/15/2016
Start Time: 03:10 (HH:MM)

If the duration of the rainfall is 15.58 hours, then what would be the End Date and End time? This has be calculated for many similar events in the dataframe with different time and durations.

Hence the desired output should look like:

```
 Start Date   Start Time   Duration (hours)   End Date      End Time 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
8/15/2016       3:10        15.58         8/15/2016      19:08
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), for extract `dates` and `times` use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
Start =  pd.to_timedelta(df['Start Time'] + ':00', unit='h')
Duration =  pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration (hours)'].astype(str)
                                                  .str.replace('.',':') + ':00', unit='h')

End = df['Start Date'] + Start + Duration
df['End Date'] = End.dt.date
#str[:5] remove seconds
df['End Time'] = End.dt.time.astype(str).str[:5]

print (df)
  Start Date Start Time  Duration (hours)    End Date End Time
0 2016-08-15       3:10             15.58  2016-08-15    19:08
1 2016-08-16       6:50             29.67  2016-08-17    12:57
2 2016-07-28       1:30              8.17  2016-07-28    09:47
```

Comment: How does it work? Maybe better is add desired output in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question. End Time should be in (HH:MM) and also the date format must be the same.

Comment: Thanks. Second date will by `8/17/2016` ?

Comment: For the second event, start date would be: 8/16/2016 at 6:50. Duration of the rainfall is 29.67 hours and ends on 8/17/2016.